# How to set supported device type in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console, android-tv

I have created an android TV application that ready to publish by the google play developer console. But I would like to just let users use this application on Android TV devices. (not a mobile device, tablets, etc.). How can I do that on the android studio side?

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, include:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="true" />
```

Only Android TV devices support the Leanback UI, so requiring it in the manifest effectively marks the app has TV-only.

See https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#leanback-req for further details